# Table cell display as cells using css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table as follows

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="display:table-row">
            Apple
        </td>
        <td style="display:table-row">
            Banana
        </td>
        <td style="display:table-row">
            Candle
        </td>
        <td style="display:table-row">
            Digital drive
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output is as follows

[image: table cell display set to table-row]

I want to change the output to show only the first two columns in the first row and then the last two columns in the second row without changing the structure of the table html but only changing the display property . Is there any css which lets me achive this ?

Comment: why would you structurize your html wrong, to correct it with css?

Comment: The html is a generated one i need to have different display for different screen sizes ! Hence the example is a generic one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
table td {
    border: none;
}
table td:nth-child(-n+1),td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/H8b3z/)

It will only make first two column and last two column in single row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css:

```
display: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially i would suggest don't change `td` default behaviour we have specification for each tag follow it. and you can achieve that display using `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none;` to the table-row

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Apple
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Banana
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Candle
        </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>        
       <td>
            Digital drive
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```